# Forcefully stop AsyncTasks doing database calls in a Fragment when a new Activity or Fragment is started

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-gridview

I am trying to populate a GridView with images from the web, for which I am calling a webservice (I don't have direct url to images).
And for that I am using Volley imageRequest.

Everything is working great, except that it takes some time to populate, which is OK when I am on the same Fragment or Activity.
But when I click on each cell, it should open up in another Activity and when the GridView is still populating it takes a long time to open the other Activity.

Can anyone please suggest me how to stop all the asynchronous database calls when I want to launch another Activity?
I tried using `ifCancelled()` in `doInBackground()` and also inside `postExecute()`.
I tried to cancel the task inside `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()`, `onDetach()`.

Nothing seems to be working.
I also tried using Picasso and Glide, but they need a direct URL.

My async task:

```
    private class GridImageTask extends AsyncTask<DevicePhoto, Void, Bitmap> {
        private int mPosition;
        private ViewHolder mHolder;
        private volatile boolean running = true;
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;


    public GridImageTask(int position, ViewHolder holder) {
        mPosition = position;
        mHolder = holder;
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(mHolder.imageview);
    }



    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(DevicePhoto... arg0) {
        Bitmap retBitmap = null;

      //  if(mTask.isCancelled()){
          //  retBitmap = null;
       // }else if(mTask.getStatus() != Status.PENDING || mTask.getStatus() != Status.FINISHED) {

        Log.i(TAG, "mTask.isCancelled()==="+mTask.isCancelled());
        Log.i(TAG, "mTask.running()==="+mTask.running);
        Log.i(TAG, "mTask.position()==="+mTask.mPosition);
        if(!isCancelled()){
            DevicePhoto photo = arg0[0];
            requestPicture(mPosition, photo);
            retBitmap = images.get(mPosition).thumbnail;
            //notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        return retBitmap;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        running = true;
        //super.onCancelled();
    }

  @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {

        mTask.cancel(true);

        running = false;
        //super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }
       // bitmap = images.get(mPosition).thumbnail;
        if (mHolder.id == mPosition && bitmap != null) {

            if (imageViewReference != null) {

                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 200, false);
                ImageView imageview = (SnapCheckableImageView) imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageview != null) {
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    //notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

I call the following method with in my adapter class from fragment in onStop().

onStop() of gridFragment class I call the following method:

```
public void cancelAsynTaskOnStop(){

 //   Log.i(TAG, "cancelAsynTaskOnStop mTask.running >>>> "+mTask.running+ "mPosition == "+mTask.mPosition+" hmTaskMap.size() == "+hmTaskMap.size()+" task.getStatus() >> "+mTask.getStatus());

    if(mTask != null){
        mTask.cancel(true);
        mTask.running = false;
    }

    if(hmTaskMap.size() > 0){
        Iterator itr = hmTaskMap.keySet().iterator();


        while(itr.hasNext()){
            GridImageTask task = (GridImageTask)hmTaskMap.get(itr.next());
            Log.i(TAG, "task.running === "+task.running+" task.mposition === "+task.mPosition+" status == "+task.getStatus());
            if(task != null){
                task.cancel(true);
                task.running = false;

                Log.i(TAG, "inside task.running === "+task.running+" task.mposition === "+task.mPosition+" status == "+task.getStatus());
            }
```

Comment: Some code will be helpful.

Comment: Where and how do you cancel AsyncTask? Also cannot find [request canceling](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#cancel)

Comment: I am calling asynctask inside my getView() method in adapter.

Comment: I am not sure how to do request cancelling. Should I call that inside fragment?

Comment: by doing request cancelling onstop, the task gets cancelled. thanks its working now.

Comment: Thanks a ton Maxim G, its working as intended.. :)

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask.cancel() doesn’t kill the Thread with no regard for the consequences. All it does is set the AsyncTask to a “cancelled” state. It’s up to the developer of AsyncTask to adhere cancel state.

And AsyncTask should not be used for long operations, because it can [block other worker tasks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)).

Comment: How else do you think i populate the gridview with images from web (with no direct image urls)? Please advice

Comment: You may consider service.